# Angular 6 - Binding value and index in html

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a ngFor loop which is returning data from my database.

I have a couple of fields called 'songStartedTime_1', 'songStartedTime_2' and this could be any number.

Is it possible to combine values in the html.

For example:

```
<div> {{ result.songStartedTime_ + i }} </div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to return all the 'songStartedTime_' plus the index which should hopefully correspond to the songStartedTime_1, songStartedTime_2 etc.

```
<li *ngFor="let result of results | async let i = index">
  <div *ngFor='let in of counter(result.songStartedCount);let i = index'>
      {{ result.songStartedTime_ + 1 }}
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you add the dummy data for `results` and expected output, so that it will give a better picture?

Answer (score 0):

instead of songStartedTime_1, songStartedTime_2 you should store songStartedTime in an array

like `songStartedTime = ['1:00', '2:00', '3:00' ];`

and then

```
<div*ngFor="let time of songStartedTime">
  <div>{{ time}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all the keys inside result:

*.component.ts

```js
public getAllResultKeys(): string[] {
    return Array.from(Object.keys(result));
}
```

*.component.html

```html
<div*ngFor="let key of getAllResultKeys()">
  <div>{{ result[key] }}</div>
</div>
```

If you want only keys with pattern songStartedTime_[some number]
*.component.ts

```js
public getAllResultKeys(): string[] {
    return Array.from(Object.keys(result))
        .filter(key => key.startsWith("songStartedTime_");
}
```